# Unicode play icon ▶ present in a page title is incorrectly displayed in my Firefox

Tags: windows-7, firefox, fonts, unicode

*Right-pointing triangle* Unicode character ▶ (U+25B6), most notably used on YouTube, is vertically squashed on my tabs, title tooltip and in history in my Firefox 24 beta on particular Windows 7 computers (it did not work in FF 22.0 nor 23.0.1 either).

It is displayed correctly on Windows taskbar tabs and inside web pages themselves - compare the play icons in following printscreen (they should look the same):

[image: original video is from vimeo.com/71278954, I needed to illustrate the incorrectly displayed play icon on youtube though]

Funny thing is, it displays correctly on 3 computers I used in Slovakia a few days ago, but incorrectly on 3 computers here in the UK. And no, changing the Region and Language -> Format setting did not help.

I also ran all the Windows updates, changed Windows font size, installed a beta version of Firefox, ran it without addons - nothing helped so far.

I am lost - **what Windows/Firefox setting changes the appearance of this character?**

Comment: Have you tried to run Firefox the ["old way"](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/what-happened-to-the-file-edit-and-view-menus#w_hidden-menu-bar)?.
Other than that, first thing that popped up my mind was some sort of [mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake)

Comment: the character displayed correctly on another computer with the menu hidden. unfortunately I don't have the troubleshooting info from the working firefox for comparison what exactly is different. and it is not a different character since both texts are the same - from `<title>...</title>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: the problem has been fixed at least since Firefox 34, but probably even in some previous versions.

Disabling **Hardware Acceleration** fixed the problem for me.

Firefox > Options > Advanced > General tab > uncheck *Use hardware acceleration when available* in Browsing section

reference: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/968277