# Unicode play icon ▶ present in a page title is incorrectly displayed in Chrome/Win XP x86

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome, fonts, unicode

This happens in 2 different machines both running Chrome Versão 29.0.1547.57 m in Windows XP Pro SP3 x86:

[image]

I've found to this question ([Unicode play icon ▶ present in a page title is incorrectly displayed in my Firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/633843/unicode-play-icon-present-in-a-page-title-is-incorrectly-displayed-in-my-firef)) and tried the same solution in chrome but didn't solve it.

EDIT: Same thing happens in IE8, but not in Firefox.

Comment: The character isn't present in MS Sans Serif, which is the font used for window chrome in Windows XP. I suppose you could try changing the menu font in the Display control panel; replacing MS Sans Serif with a font containing the glyph in question ("BLACK RIGHT POINTING TRIANGLE", code point 0x25b6) should solve the problem.

Comment: 2 questions, which font style might have that glyph? And also in Windows XP>Ctrl. Panel>Display>Appearance>Advanced i need to choose an item to change the font? You know which it might be, or do i have to change them all?

Comment: The easiest way to find a font containing the character will be via the Character Map (Start -> Run 'charmap', OK); use the search options to find the code point, and then select various fonts until you find one with the glyph. The item to select in the Control Panel is the menus; changing that font should produce the desired result. (Sorry to be vague; I no longer have access to a Windows XP box and am therefore going on memory.)

Comment: i couldn't find the font in charmap so i googled and found [this](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25b6/fontsupport.htm), tried Arial Unicode MS in the Menu Item, restarted, but still i can't get the triangle :(